# How to send an XMLHttpRequest based on a request?

Tags: javascript, post, xmlhttprequest

The request is as following: [image]

Now I want write javascript to send XMLHttpRequest to submit the form using POST request. What I've written down is the following which is incorrect. Can anyone correct me here.

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
            var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
            x.open("POST","www.something.com/vv",true);
            x.withCredentials = true;
            x.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            x.send(JSON.stringify({"email":"xxx@icloud.com", "password":"XXXX", "type": "icloud"})); 
        }, false);
    </script>
```

Comment: Why not use `fetch`?

Comment: How to do it with fetch?

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59384154/10431732)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Using the Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) courtesy of MDN. For a `POST` request using [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) makes it pretty easy.

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("email": "xxx.icloud.com");
formData.append("password": "XXXX");
formData.append("type": "icloud");
fetch("https://www.something.com/vv", {method: "POST", body: formData});
```

However, using `POST` with `FormData` will set the `Content-Type` header to `multipart/form-data`. If you really do need it to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` then you should manually set the content type header and form data [like in this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Supplying_request_options).

```
fetch("https://www.something.com/vv", {
  method: "POST", 
  body: JSON.stringify({...yourFormDataObject}), 
  headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
});
```

`fetch` has 93%+ support, works on all modern browsers, and can easily be polyfilled. https://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch